# how to burn the total supply without burning account balances

Tags: solidity, erc-20

```
// Removes x amount from totalSupply
    function burnTokens(uint tokens) external onlyOwner freezeFunction returns (bool success) {
        require(totalSupply != 0, "unable to burn below 0 total supply");
        require(tokens != 0, "unable to burn 0 tokens");
        
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(tokens);
        emit TokensBurned(tokens);
        return true;
    }
```

So my code burns tokens from the supply, but I recently found out that if there are x amount of tokens in someone's account and that's the whole supply (due to a dynamic supply), then their tokens are burned also. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You're not burning anything here, just reducing the value of the `totalSupply` variable (to zero, I would assume). By doing that, you are probably demolishing the correct functionality of your token contract (though there's no way of knowing that for sure, because you haven't provided the relevant source code). The complete image of balances should be stored in a `balances` mapping (or whatever you choose to name this variable). In order to complete this image and allow for the correct functionality of your token contract, the `totalSupply` variable is also important.

Comment: Cheers, that helped me out. Ended up making a seperate totalSupplyHeld and make sure the total supply doesn't go under it, unless there are no holders.